# Can I create a custom domain with the IBM Watson Machine Translation API?

Tags: ibm-watson

My goal is to create a custom translation engine for the financial domain, language pair CHT - EN and CHS - EN. I have respective dictionaries and aligned segments ready to import into a custom engine and train the engine.

If I understand the documentation (https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/language-translation/) correctly, I can only build on top of existing domains and language pairs. So, for Chinese - English, I could only select the patents domain and import my own dictionaries and corpus, then re-train. Not sure though if this makes sense, also it is unclear if we are talking traditional Chinese or simplified Chinese. I need traditional Chinese service first, later on simplified Chinese.

An alternative would be to build on top of a financial news domain, but news are not available for Chinese - English.

I'm trying to figure out the best practice how to go ahead and appreciate any guidance.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe your reading of the docs is correct in that the service only supports customization of existing domain/language pairs. I'm looking into the traditional vs simplified Chinese question.

Comment: Update: the service supports both Traditional and Simplified Chinese using "unihan". Not sure how that works for output, but you can at least input both variations as the source language.

Answer (score 0):

To create a model you can use a glossary with high frequency or high confidence phrase translations or a parallel corpus(TMX file) instead.

As @Nathan said, if you use `zh-en-patent` as `base_model_id` you will have support for both Traditional and Simplified Chinese using [unihan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_unification). `zh-en-patent` is the only model that you can use **today** to translate Chinese to English.

Here is a guide on how to create a custom translation model using the [IBM Watson Language Translator service](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/language-translator/customizing.html#customizing).